# SQL: Find common rows in different record

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables:

- Teacher Table (t_id, email, ...)
- Student Table (s_id, email, ...)
- Teaching Table (t_id, s_id, class_time, ...)

I have a task which is, given two t_id, find the common students that these 2 teachers have taught.

Is it possible to accomplish this in strictly SQL? If not I might try to retrieve out the student records individually based on different teacher, and do a search to see which students they have in common. This seems a bit overkill for something that seems possible to write a SQL query for.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. All as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Yes. It's possible. what rdbms are you working with? what version? what have you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can self join to get students for both teachers.

```
DECLARE @TeacherID1 INT = 1
DECLARE @TeacherID2 INT = 2

SELECT 
    StudentID = T1.s_id,
    Teacher1 = T1.t_id,
    Teacher1ClassTime = T1.class_time ,
    Teacher2 = T2.t_id,
    Teacher2ClassTime = T2.class_time 
FROM 
    TeachingTable T1
    INNER JOIN TeachingTable T2 ON T2.s_id=T1._sid AND T2.t_id=@TeacherID2
WHERE 
    T1.t_id = @TeacherID1
ORDER BY
    T1.ClassTime
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select s_id 
from student a
inner join teaching b on a.s_id = b.s_id
where t_id = 'First give t_id'
INTERSECT 
select s_id 
from student a
inner join teaching b on a.s_id = b.s_id
where t_id = 'Second give t_id'
```

This work with MS DB, but probably not with others.

```
select s_id 
from student a
inner join teaching b on a.s_id = b.s_id
where b.t_id = 'First give t_id'
and s_id in (
select s_id 
from student c
inner join teaching d on c.s_id = d.s_id
where d.t_id = 'Second give t_id'
)
```

the second one should work with any DB.